# Extracting data from scrapy into array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I know scrapy 'extracts()' data into an array and this is great to modify it in the pipeline I need it to stay in an array.

Unfortunately when I pull data like this -

```
In [8]: response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
Out[8]: u'98.139.135.129'
```

I need to get Out[8]: u'98.139.135.129 back in an array like this --

```
[u'98.139.135.129']
```

Hah, how do I do that?  I can't find anything like this in the forum... thanks!

Ok, where do I put the []

```
item["Attribute"][0]['value']  = response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your expression is a string. The `[]` symbols are used to create an array:

```
foo = ['somestring']
```

For your specific example:

```
foo = [response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]]
```

You can also use array slicing:

```
In [1]: foo = ['bar', 'baz']
In [2]: foo[:1]
Out[2]: ['bar']
```

Which makes your example:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()[:1]
```